# How to set up a Windows 10 kiosk account to run a UWP launcher app that launchs others UWP apps?

Tags: c#, uwp, launcher, kiosk-mode

I have developed an UWP launcher app that can launch other UWP apps. **It works fine in a normal Windows 10 account** (not kiosk).

The code to launch the UWP applications:

```
        private async void RunApplication(string appURI)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(appURI);

            try
            {
                bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
                if (!result)
                {
                    _logger.LogErrorWithTime("Error on lauching application " + appURI);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInfoWithTime("Application " + appURI + " was launched sucessfully.");
                }
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                _logger.LogErrorWithTime("Error on opening app uri " + appURI, e );
            }
        }
```

**When I run it in a Kiosk account, windows does not allow the launcher to launch others UWP** applications, even the Windows Calculator, that is a not restricted UWP app.

**Is there a way to run an UWP launcher on Kiosk mode that is allowed to launch other UWP applications?**

I am running at a desktop computer, Intel i7 64 bits, with Windows 10 Pro, version 22H2.

I have turned off all windows security configurations as Anti-virus, firewall, etc...

I have done some extra configurations on Windows, like this PowerShell script below, but it did not work as well.

```
# Define the account user name and the account path 
$KioskUserName = "JohnKiosk"
$KioskUserFolderPath = "C:\Users\$($KioskUserName)"

Write-Host "Setting up the Kiosk mode multiple applications to the user $UserName."

# Set the user model Id for the UWP application 
$UWPAppUserModelId = "App1_0q5sqegcbs4qe!App"

# Set the registry key where the configurations are applyed 
$RegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\$KioskUserName"

# Set the key registry for the Kiosk account 
New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null

# Set the Registry key to start the UWP application on the kiosk account
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "Shell" -Value "explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\$UWPAppUserModelId"

# Set the list of allowed applications on the kiosk account
$AllowedApps = @(
    "App1_0q5sqegcbs4qe!App",
    "App2_0q5sqegcbs4qe!App",
    "App3_0q5sqegcbs4qe!App",
    "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App",
)

# SEt the registry key where the configurations are applyed
$RegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AssignedAccess\$KioskUserName"

# Create the registry key to the target user 
New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null

# Set the subkey 'AllowedApps'
$AllowedAppsPath = "$RegistryPath\AllowedApps"
New-Item -Path $AllowedAppsPath -Force | Out-Null

# Set the registry values
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "IsAssignedAccess" -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "DisplayName" -Value $KioskUserName
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "User" -Value $KioskUserName

# Set the allowed applications on the subkey "AllowedApps"
$AllowedApps | ForEach-Object {
    New-ItemProperty -Path $AllowedAppsPath -Name $_ -Value "" -PropertyType String -Force | Out-Null
}

# Set all possible permissions to the Kiosk account (be carefull here )
icacls $KioskUserFolderPath /grant "$KioskUserName`:(OI`)(CI`)F" /T /C /Q

Write-Host "The kiosk account mode with multiple applications was applyed to the $KioskUserName."
```